# Why isn't my NHibernate update working?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm currently using the ASP.NET Web Api along with NHibernate & Autofac...I'm having an issue where my update is not being committed to the database.  I'm using an ActionFilterAttribute to open and close a transcation every time an action is performed like so:

```
private ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

public TransactionAttribute()
{
    SessionFactory = WebApiApplication.SessionFactory;
}

public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    session.BeginTransaction();
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    var transcation = session.Transaction;
    if (transcation != null && transcation.IsActive)
    {
        transcation.Commit();
    }
    session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
    session.Close();
}
```

Which works fine for the add, read, and delete functions in my repository.  Unfortunately, my update doesn't seem to be working (though I've tried it several ways):

```
public bool Update(Client client)
{
    var result = Get(client.ClientID);

    if (result == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    result.Name = client.Name;
    result.Acronym = client.Acronym;
    result.Website = client.Website;

    return true;
}
```

From what I've read if modifying an object during a transaction, there's no need to manually call Update or SaveOrUpdate, as this is tracked by NHibernate & performed when the transaction is committed.

Why would my update function not be working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is Update called from? What is Get? More code, those snippets are useless.

Comment: Euphoric, here's my full repository class: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bsQFL1fs

Comment: I would really check in debugger if all sessions/transaction are same for the course of Action. There might be some creation of other sessions/transactions somewhere. I would try to strip the code to basic session/get/update/commit and slowly add additional code to check what piece of code causes this error.

Comment: What session context have you configured? When are where are you creating the repository instance - are you sure it use the same contextual session?

Comment: First thing I would do is download a trial copy of NhProf and make sure my session transactions are being used correctly. http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/hprof

Comment: you are probably missing a session.Flush() if you don't have a transaction.,

Comment: I'm using AutoFac to control my session lifetime.  This is what my code looks like to do this: http://pastebin.com/z95bQJ1L..Basically I'm creating and injecting a client repository at each API call, which is then injected with an ISession (once again at each API call).  Is something wrong with this approach?

Comment: Rippo, I do believe that there's an issue with my sessions.  Not sure why this would be happening, but it appears that somehow the session pulling the object (before attempting to update it) is separate from the transaction session?  See the report here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/153lse0iy9e9oka/Export.html (you'll obviously need to download to view it properly).

Comment: It seems like this  secondary, independent session is created in my OnActionExecuting code directly after the line CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own--basically I was creating 2 sessions (one in my TranscationAttribute and one due to DI into my repository).  The reason it was creating two is pretty explicit in the OnActionExecuting statement...I'm not checking to see whether any session factory is currently bound to the CurrentSessionContext.  This is the new code I'm using:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(SessionFactory))
        {
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
        }

        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        session.BeginTransaction();
    }
```

The issue I had after implementing this code is that the logic is not sound..when the session is DI'ed into my repository ISession, it was not being automatically bound.  My solution was to bind it in the constructor of my repository like so:

```
    public ClientRepository(ISession session) 
    {
        if (session == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("nhSession");
        this._session = session;
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_session);
    }
```

But I'm not 100% sure that this is going to be safe with many simultaneous HTTP requests...going to bring this question over to code review unless someone has an answer for me here!

Thanks!